# How to use a while loop to print every nth number in a range in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, iteration

I'm working on a practice problem that says, "Use a "while" loop to print out every fifth number counting from 1 to 1000."

I can't seem to make it work.

This is what I've tried so far (as well as several small tweaks of this).

```
num = 1

while num in range(1, 1001):
    if num % 5 == 0:
        num += 1
print(num)
```

Thank you!

Comment: `print range(1, 1001, 5)` ?

Comment: @khachik `use a "while" loop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. 
You want to print out every time the condition matches, but increment regardless of the condition.

```
num = 1

while num in range(1, 1001):
    if num % 5 == 0:
        print(num)  # print must be inside the condition
    num += 1  # the increase must be done on every iteration
```

Comment: you don't need to instatiate num at the begining. You can remove that line.

Comment: That's it! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @narm: yes you have, this is not a for loop.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work if I remove the first line. It works exactly the way you wrote it @Toby

Comment: @Toby yeah i messed up, but the use of that instantiation with `range()` just seems strange.

Comment: @narn: agreed, one would normally use a for loop for such a task. But the task is to use a while loop. One could also use the step argument to range and print on every iteration, but I am not sure that is what was asked.

Answer (score 3):

I would say Python style would be more like:

```py
print(list(range(0, 1001, 5)[1:]))
```

Got you, yes then for `while` loop it looks like:

```py
num = 1
while num < 1001:
    if not num % 5:
        print(num)
    num += 1
```

Comment: That is better, but the exercise was to use a while loop 

Answer (score 1):

```
for num in range(1, 1001):
    if num % 5 == 0:
        print(num)
```

You were pretty close, this should work.

@Wolf comment is also very helpful for you and relevant!

Comment: You need to `use a "while" loop`

Comment: I can do it with a for loop :) Thank you! I can't figure out how to do it with a while loop.

Comment: Alright, I was just working on the solution with a while-loop. :) You are welcome!

Comment: I'm sorry, what I mean is that the for loop you wrote was helpful, but I need to know how to do it while a while loop :)

Comment: Look up the recent answers. They provide the solution. :)